# Sampling Intervals for Azure Metrics

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

Could you please help understand how azure metrics are calculated. For an example, we can see the request/total request graph, and a number at a given point in time (say 6000 at 4.34 PM) for Azure API Management. The request count has no meaning at a given point in time, but a measure for a given "period" of time. When i research, i found that the number represent the number of request received during the sampling interval.However, no further data is available on what the sampling interval is. Azure portal/metrics graphs has no setting to  view/change sampling interval either.

So what's the sampling interval used for Azure metrics? or what does the total request count meaning at a given point in time?

(However, the application insight metrics allow you to set the sampling interval)

could you please shed some light? thanks

Comment: Typically - ‘Requests’ - The total number of requests regardless of their resulting HTTP status code and where as ‘Requests In Application Queue’ is  the number of requests in the application request queue.
You can always change the 'chart Setting' for much detailed info, by going into the metric and ellipsis (...) /settings

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment from AjayKumar-MSFT is correct, so I summarize if it could help others:

Typically - ‘Requests’ - The total number of requests regardless of their resulting HTTP status code and where as ‘Requests In Application Queue’ is the number of requests in the application request queue. You can always change the 'chart Setting' for much detailed info, by going into the metric and ellipsis (...) /settings